# Sly.js make horizontal scroller

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to use Sly.js: http://darsa.in/sly/. I want it to look like the one in the header on the website (with the left and right arrows). I tried reading the documentation and made this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="sly.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="horizontal.css"> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="scrollbar">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame">
            <ul class="slidee">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>      

    </body>
</html>
```

However, the scrollbar doesn't work. I only see the boxes with numbers on them. If anyone can help me figure out how to make this work, it would be greatly appreciated.